# Why is the cookie expiring immediately?

Tags: php, cookies

In my code (testing on my local machine with domain localdev.xxx.com) I use the following code to set a cookie in browser which will expire in 6 months time:

```
$cookieExpiresOn = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 184);
setcookie("ref", "somevalue", $cookieExpiresOn);
```

however when I check the http response using firebug the set-cookie header has the date set to 1st of January 1970.

```
Set-Cookie: ref=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;
```

Isn't `time()` function supposed to return the current date and time since Unix Epoch time? Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you put "ref=deleted"? In your sample code, it says "somevalue" instead. Maybe a later line of code re-sets the cookie?

Comment: just a quick test: change ref to _ref and see if its set, always a possibility somewhere else in your app ref is being overwritten.

Comment: the time() function is a bit quirky sometimes. Sometimes doing time()+whatever and defining it within a variable will work, sometimes it won't quick work around kinda is define time() as its own variable, then do your math to it on the next line... Also just double check what your cooieExpiresOn really is, maybe its a number out of range, and thus causing it to defualt to something that is, but wont work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found what the problem was. In my actual code the value was being set through a variable like so:

```
setcookie("ref", $varx, $cookieExpiresOn);
```

Apparently if cookie value is an empty string then php attempts to delete the cookie by setting its expire date to before current GMT time.